# Docker postgress User "postgres" has no password assigned

Tags: postgresql, docker

I keep getting

> User "postgres" has no password assigned.

updated

[image]

**.env**

```
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=demo_db2
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

Even though the postgres password is set.

I'm trying to use the same variables from the following command

```
docker run --name demo4 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres
```

Could this be an issue with volumes ? im very confused.

I ran this command as well

```
 docker run -it --rm --name demo4 -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_USER=postgress postgres:9.4
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=database
  database:
    image: postgres:9.6.8-alpine
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata
    ports:
      - 8002:5432
  react_client:
      build:
        context: ./client
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      image: react_client
      working_dir: /home/node/app/client
      volumes:
        - ./:/home/node/app
      ports:
        - 8001:8001
      env_file:
        - ./client/.env
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the inclusion of the `.env` file...

Docker composer:

```
database:
  environment:
    - ENV_VAR=VALUE
```

or

```
database:
  env_file:
    - .env
```

Plain Docker:

```
docker run options --env ENV_VAR=VALUE ...
```

or

```
docker run options --env-file .env ...`
```

Comment: it still hasn't changed the error, i updated the post so you can see the sort of error it shows.

Comment: i used `database:
  env_file:
    - .env`

Comment: could this be a volumes issue ?

Comment: This is nothing related with volumes. The `.env` must be the name of the file you are using for the environment variables and your application also needs to read the values from the same file .

Comment: it is, do i need to add `POSTGRES_DB=demo_db2` 
`POSTGRES_USER=postgres`
`POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password` into the docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: Try also to remove the docker containers and start them again `docker-compose down && docker-compose up` .

Comment: If you don't add all the env vars then it will use the default ones and you application need to use also them, so best practice is to declare alll env vars.

Comment: so yes add the env variables into the docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: i think i fixed it. with your help

Comment: thank you :) i ended up not adding the environment variables, im still unsure what i did. but i see `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Users" ("id"   SERIAL , "username" VARCHAR(255), "email" VARCHAR(255), "password" VARCHAR(255), "resetPasswordToken" VARCHAR(255), "resetPasswordExpires" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));`

so that means its working